# Compile time error checking of a customisable state machine (with substate support) in C++11

Tags: c++11, state, variadic-templates

I'm working on the design of a general state machine using C++ 11. Because of the use of `std::string` to identify states, I can only catch errors at runtime. I would like to change this to catch errors when specifying states in the code at compile time.

I have been playing with a couple ideas based on variadic templates and enum class, but haven't found a solution yet, at least not one that is reasonably clean/readable.

Some snippets of my current state machine are below with the full runnable code at: http://cpp.sh/26njm

```
SState sStateChart("fsm", {
   SState("init", {
      SState("init_foo"),
      SState("init_bar"),
   }),
   SState("count", {
      SState("count_foo"),
      SState("count_bar"),
   }),
   SState("display", {
      SState("display_foo"),
      SState("display_bar"),
   }),
});
```

The constructor of `SState` takes a `std::string` for the state ID, and then a `std::vector<SState>` initialized via a initialization list for the substates as follows:

```
struct SState {
   SState(const std::string& str_id,
          const std::vector<SState>& vec_sub_states = {}) :
      Id(str_id),
      SubStates(vec_sub_states) {
   }
   //...
   std::string Id;
   std::vector<SState> SubStates;
   //...
};
```

The state chart can then be further defined using the following syntax:

**Methods**

```
std::function<void()> fnInitFoo = [&] {
   std::cerr << "fnInitFoo" << std::endl;
   foo = 0;
};
sStateChart["init"]["init_foo"].SetEntryFunction(fnInitFoo);
```

**Transitions**

```
std::function<bool()> fnTransInitFooInitBar = [&] {
   return (bar != 0);
};
sStateChart["init"].AddTransition("init_foo","init_bar", fnTransDisplayToInit);
```

And for the sake of interest, this is what I was working on regarding a hierarchy of states based on a variadic template. I have abandoned this idea for the moment as it was getting complicated without showing any signs of solving my problem - I thought I could somehow pass a enum class as one of the parameters to the template, but it wasn't any better than my example using strings...

```
template<class... SUBSTATES> class CState {};

template<class STATE, class... SUBSTATES>
class CState<STATE, SUBSTATES...> : private CState<SUBSTATES...> {


};

enum class ETopLevelStates {INIT, COUNT, DISPLAY};
enum class EInitStates {INIT_FOO, INIT_BAR};

int main() {
   CState<
      CState<
         CState<>,
         CState<>
      >,
      CState<>,
      CState<>
   > cStateMachine;

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: are you doing this just for educational purposes? how about [boost::msm](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/msm/doc/HTML/index.html)?

Comment: partly for educational purposes, i.e. learning to leverage the new features in C++11 - I have written a FSM using boost statechart before, and it ended up being very difficult to read...

Comment: boost statechart and boost meta state machine are two different libraries, not sure which one you used

Comment: I will have another look at meta state machine, I previously used statechart. Although I would like to avoid boost and use standard c++ when and wherever possible...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this compiles and could be a starting point for something interesting:

```
/* States */
enum class EState : unsigned int {
   FSM,
   INIT, INIT_FOO, INIT_BAR,
   COUNT, COUNT_FOO, COUNT_BAR,
   DISPLAY, DISPLAY_FOO, DISPLAY_BAR
};

template<EState STATE, class... SUBSTATES> class CState {};

int main() {

   CState<EState::FSM,
      CState<EState::INIT,
         CState<EState::INIT_FOO>,
         CState<EState::INIT_BAR>
      >,
      CState<EState::COUNT,
         CState<EState::COUNT_FOO>,
         CState<EState::COUNT_BAR>
      >,
      CState<EState::DISPLAY,
         CState<EState::DISPLAY_FOO>,
         CState<EState::DISPLAY_BAR>
      >
   > cStateMachine;

   return 0;
}
```

I guess I could then proceeded such as in `std::tuple` and inherit from `class... SUBSTATES`. What would then be nice is if I could write something along the lines of:

```
cStateMachine.AddTransition(EState::COUNT_FOO, EState::COUNT_BAR);
```